# Jsoup Extract only this tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this html code: [code html](http://pastebin.com/u0J78dyh)

I just want "a" tag contained in "td" tag.

I tried this:

```
    Elements tables = body.getElementsByTag("table");

    for (Element table : tables) {

        if (table.className().toLowerCase().contains("infobox")) {

            Elements link=table.getElementsByTag("a");

            for(Element el:link)
                System.out.println(el.text());


            break;
        }

}
```

but it extracts the tag "a" of "th" and "td" while I just want the tag "a" of "td". 
Thank you.

**EDIT**
I solved this way:

```
Elements tables = body.getElementsByTag("table");

    for (Element table : tables) {

        if (table.className().toLowerCase().contains("infobox")) {


            Elements t1 = table.select("td");
            Elements t2 = t1.select("a");

            for(Element el:t2)
                System.out.println(el.text());


            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: you want that from a table with class infobox? is a direct child of td?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simple you can do

```
for(Element e : doc.select("table.infobox td a")){
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```